# How do I enlarge my boxplot?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, jupyter, figsize

[image]

How can I enlarge my boxplot in jupyter? I can't find any optional parameters that allows me to do so. specifically using seaborn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using `rc` parameter in `seaborn`:

```
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(11,8)})
```

where `(11,8)` refers 11 inch width and 8 inch height.

You can also enlarge font by passing font_scale parameter along with style to change background from default. Using example from [seaborn boxplot example][1]:

```
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline

sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(11,8)}, font_scale=1.5, style='whitegrid')

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
sns.boxplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips);
```

Screenshot for result in Jupyter Notebook:

The default with no change would give:
[image]

After the change as above would give:
[image]

Comment: The code does allow a change in size within Jupyter notebooks.